# Validar campos de textos en php

Tags: php, validación

estoy haciendo un formulario en php y necesito validar que los campos no estén vacíos. Sin embargo cuando se escriben ESPACIOS VACIOS en el input, mi función está regresando un valor verdadero. Entonces la pregunta concreta sería:
¿Como validar que un input no inice con espacios vacíos pero que si los acepte?
Por ejemplo, para el campo **Nombre:** Jesús Adrían (Es un nombre compuestos por dos nombres y lleva un espacio en medio).

Actualmente mi función es esta:

```
public static function validarTexto($texto){
        if($texto==""){
            return false;
        }else{
            $patron = '/^[a-zA-Z, ]*$/';
            if(preg_match($patron,$texto)){
                return true;     
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Aquí un ejemplo de lo que me sucede:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por su oportuna ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno, me "sumergí un poco más a la documentación de PHP y me encontré con la función que necesitaba.

(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)

**trim** — Elimina espacio en blanco (u otro tipo de caracteres) del inicio y el final de la cadena.

Esta función devuelve una cadena con los espacios en blanco eliminados del inicio y final del str. sin el segundo parámetro, trim() eliminará estos caracteres:

" " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), espacio simple.

"\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), tabulación.

"\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), salto de línea.

"\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), retorno de carro.

"\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), el byte NUL.

"\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), tabulación vertical.

Más detalles:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.trim.php

Al final mi función quedó así:

```
public static function validarTexto($texto){
        $texto = trim($texto);
        if($texto=="" && trim($texto)==""){
            return false;
        }else{
            $patron = '/^[a-zA-Z, ]*$/';
            if(preg_match($patron,$texto)){
                return true;   
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto tal vez te ayude:

```
if(!isset($_POST['mi_campo']) || strlen(trim($_POST['mi_campo'])) == 0){
    die('El campo es vacio'); //aquí lo personalizas
}
```

Revisamos si está seteada la variable y que su tamaño no sea cero.

Comment: Gracias, esa opción también me funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar lo siguiente:

```php
public static function validarTexto($texto) {
    return !empty(trim($texto));
}
```

La función nativa `trim()` de PHP se usa para quitar los espacios en los bordes de tu cadena de texto. Esto quiere decir, quita los espacios al principio y al final de la cadena.

La función nativa `empty()` de PHP retorna verdadero (boolean) si el valor que recibe está vacío.

Referencia de ambas funciones:

- [PHP: trim - Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.trim.php)
- [PHP: empty - Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 0):

El primer filtrado de una entrada de texto pasaría por la función **trim()**, con esta se eliminan los espacios en blanco al principio y al final de una cadena de texto, todo su contenido si sólo hay espacios, con lo que obtenemos una cadena sin espacios extras en el primer caso y una cadena vacía en el segundo (no se introdujo contenido útil) que nos permita continuar con la lógica de las validaciones.

Tu método de limpieza, reescrita quedaría así:

```
public static function validateStrContent($str)
{
    $str = trim($str);
    if ($str !== '') {
        $pattern = '/^[a-zA-Z, ]*$/';
        if (preg_match($pattern, $str)) {
            return true;   
        }
    }

    return false;   
}
```

Si añadimos tipado, recomendable para PHP7, sería:

```
public static function validateStrContent(string $str): bool
{
    $str = trim($str);
    if ($str !== '') {
        $pattern = '/^[a-zA-Z, ]*$/';
        if (preg_match($pattern, $str)) {
            return true;   
        }
    }

    return false;   
}
```